In Texas Holdem what is the probability that the best hand is on the table?
The brute force method would involve calculating the probability of a royal flush on the table (i.e., the five community cards are A, K, Q, J, T suited). Follow this by calculating the probability that the five community cards form a straight flush AND the probability that none of the players has a better hand (which depends on the number of players). Etc. etc.
Can anyone suggest a shortcut?

Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. The body of the question should be self-contained - do not assume that the reader will read the title. As for the mathematics: as your text suggests, you first need to specify all the relevant parameters, such as the number of players - we can't fill in "etc., etc." for you.

For each board you can find the sets of two cards that can improve it, then compute the probability of those.  For a royal flush there are none.  For a straight flush they are the card just above and if a player has that one the one above that although the probability of some hand beating the board just depends on the one immediately above.  For four of a kind it is any card above the odd card on the board and so on.  That will reduce the computation somewhat, but it is still a lot of cases.
